# Move files via ajax request (which Jquery.ajax() options are almost necessery to use)

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp-2.1

When a user clicks on a link, I want to move the files from one folder to another (by ajax)

The php move file works fine, but the ajax part doesnt seem to be working.

**Ajax called in JS script:**

```
    function moveFiles() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/website/controller/moveFiles",
        });
    }
```

**(Cake)PHP function**

```
public function moveTmpFiles() {
    $source = new Folder(WWW_ROOT . "uploadify/tmpFiles");
    $unsavedFiles = new Folder(WWW_ROOT . "uploadify/unsavedFiles");
        $this->moveFiles($source->path, $destination_path->path);
}
```

**JQuery function**

```
$( "#element" ).click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    moveTmpFiles();
    $( "#myDialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

I guess I should add more options to the $.ajax call, but the **real questions here is this:**

**Which options on jquery ajax calling are necessery to get it work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a JS function named `moveFiles()` and you're calling `moveTmpFiles();`, which is the PHP function.

Change your jQuery function as follows.

```
$( "#element" ).click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    moveFiles();
    $( "#myDialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

*As a side note, do not use absolute paths. When you move your application to the production server, you'll have to change all the URLs in your code.*

Comment: Ofcourse.. thx.. after 9 hours of coding you do one copy paste and then it drives you mad for like half an hour.. thx for your time, I will mark your answer as answered and ask to close this topic.

Comment: For the URLs -> not even in the ajax calls?

Comment: Not even in the ajax calls.

Comment: altered.. again, thank you :)